# How to solve no such table: user in Heroku application?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, heroku-toolbelt

I have deploy the application but its showing me an internal server error . the same application I have run on localhost but now I am trying to run through heroku but its not giving me an output. the application is there on the link given below 
http://flask.pocoo.org/

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153486+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153487+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153488+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153489+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153491+00:00 app[web.1]:     [username], one=True)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153491+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 63, in query_db
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153493+00:00 app[web.1]: OperationalError: no such table: user
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153486+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153486+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153487+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153488+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153490+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 125, in user_timeline
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153489+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153491+00:00 app[web.1]:     [username], one=True)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153491+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 63, in query_db
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153492+00:00 app[web.1]:     cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153493+00:00 app[web.1]: OperationalError: no such table: user
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153486+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153486+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153487+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153490+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 125, in user_timeline
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153491+00:00 app[web.1]:     [username], one=True)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153491+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 63, in query_db
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153486+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153488+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153488+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153486+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153486+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153487+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153488+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153490+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 125, in user_timeline
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153491+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 63, in query_db
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153492+00:00 app[web.1]:     cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.282478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/public" host=minitwittest.herokuapp.com request_id=a93d6057-f7de-4a9b-876c-a13372c31cbc fwd="103.5.187.166" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=244
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272442+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-26 06:41:02 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Error handling request /public
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272445+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272447+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272448+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272448+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272452+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272454+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272456+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272457+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272458+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272459+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272460+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272461+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272462+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272469+00:00 app[web.1]:     order by message.pub_date desc limit ?''', [PER_PAGE]))
2015-11-26T06:41:02.272470+00:00 app[web.1]:     cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.811154+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=minitwittest.herokuapp.com request_id=3b9d3742-4940-493a-ba29-579865ca6b40 fwd="103.5.187.166" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=244
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801367+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-26 06:41:02 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Error handling request /favicon.ico
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801371+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801372+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801373+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801374+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801375+00:00 app[web.1]:     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801376+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801377+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801378+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801379+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801380+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801382+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801384+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801384+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801385+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801386+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801386+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801387+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801388+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 125, in user_timeline
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801389+00:00 app[web.1]:     [username], one=True)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801389+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 63, in query_db
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801390+00:00 app[web.1]:     cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801391+00:00 app[web.1]: OperationalError: no such table: user
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801384+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801385+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801387+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801388+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 125, in user_timeline
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801387+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801389+00:00 app[web.1]:     [username], one=True)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801391+00:00 app[web.1]: OperationalError: no such table: user
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801384+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801384+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801385+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801387+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801386+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801387+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801389+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 63, in query_db
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801390+00:00 app[web.1]:     cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
2015-11-26T06:41:02.801391+00:00 app[web.1]: OperationalError: no such table: user
```

Comment: Heroku just launched [Live Log](https://twitter.com/heroku/status/669681968041226240) And please post the error traceback here to find out what went wrong

Comment: this is the  link create while i deploy  my app http://minitwittest.herokuapp.com/public .....when running on the brwoser using this link getting Internal Server error

Comment: i want to save data of my appplication on heroku database

Comment: can you please see the log and tell me error code ... Without error code it's very hardly guess

Comment: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
 reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

Comment: File "/app/minitwit.py", line 63, in query_db File "/app/minitwit.py", line 125, in user_timeline
2015-11-26T06:31:28.153491+00:00 app[web.1]:     [username], one=True)

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback in the question ?

Comment: File "/app/minitwit.py", line 63, in query_db
app[web.1]: OperationalError: no such table: user
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 125, in user_timeline
app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

Comment: app[web.1]:     [username], one=True)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/minitwit.py", line 63, in query_db
app[web.1]:     cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
app[web.1]: OperationalError: no such table: user
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

Comment: Please update your question with full traceback... Not in command section...

Comment: If you don't know how to update... please click the edit link ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `Flask-SQLAlchemy` In that case you have to create database table first. To do that you have to enter into `heroku run python` and `from app import db` and `db.create_all()`.

Comment: i have follow the proceture but still getting me error in python

Comment: >>> from mintwit import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mintwit
>>> from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
>>> db.create_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'db' is not defined

Comment: @imdadhussain Where is your db then ?

Comment: I have to create in heroku

Comment: @imdadhussain No... You have to import your db

Comment: please tell do you have this line in your application  `( db = SQLAlchemy(app) )` ?

Comment: no i dont have but in these link  the code is there so look up and please guide me. http://flask.pocoo.org/ in these link there is a minitwit app. Please see the app an run on localhost say me how to do

Comment: oKay then you have to run `flask --app=minitwit initdb` this command in heroku

Comment: yes.. Just enter into `heroku run bash` and type this `flask --app=minitwit initdb`

Comment: @imdadhussain what happened ?

Comment: (venv) C:\Users\Abbscomp\Desktop\minitwit>heroku run bash
Running bash on minitwittest... up, run.4799
~ $ flask --app=minitwit initdb
bash: flask: command not found

Comment: do you have requirements.txt file in your application ?

Comment: yes i have in requirements.txt file i have these content Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
gunicorn==19.3.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==1.0.9
virtualenv==13.1.2
webapp2==2.5.2
Werkzeug==0.11.2
WTForms==2.0.2

Comment: i send u 3 link in that my three file minitwit.py , requirements.txt,schema.sql....http://paste.ubuntu.com/13514219/,http://paste.ubuntu.com/13514241/,http://paste.ubuntu.com/13514251/...please go on these 3 link these my code

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13523994/,http://paste.ubuntu.com/13524002/,http://paste.ubuntu.com/13524012/

Comment: bcse heroku doesnt support sqlite3 so you have to install sqlalchemy and modify all the code make it to run in heroku .. thanks

Comment: i am new please guide what i have to change